# Directory as command line argument

Tags: shell-script

From my code below, I am to search for files of size zero, and prompt the user to delete them, if they so wish. However I am lost as the script  should  allow  for  directories  to  be  specified  as command line parameters. I must use the current directory as default, if no directory is specified on the command line.
I think I am on the right track, but can not seem to figure out how to prompt the user to enter the path to the file he wishes to delete.

```
#!/bin/bash

ls -lR | grep '^-' | sort -k 5 -rn

echo "Files of size zero, relative to current directory, are as follows:"
find . -size 0 -print

echo "Would you like to delete the files of size zero?: Type yes or no"
read answer

if [[ $answer == "yes" ]]
then
    find . -type f -empty -delete
    echo "List of files with size zero files deleted:"
    ls -lR | grep '^-' | sort -k 5 -rn

else
    echo "User wishes to not delete files"
fi
```

Comment: Note I assume that the `ls` line are just there for debug. However you will not get a list of deleted files, by looking at existing files (the `echo` and `ls`, in the then clause).

Comment: Note I assume that the `ls` line are just there for debug. Do not tell the user ”User wishes to not delete files”, they know (and this is very un-Unix).

Comment: Also to make the script nicer (easier to use), create two modes: list zero size files, and remove zero size files (this is easier to use than an interactive script).

Answer (score 3):

You would use

```
topdir=${1:-.}
```

This would set the `topdir` variable to the first command line argument, unless it was missing or empty, in which case it would be set to `.`.  You would then use `"$topdir"` in your commands. Remember to double quote it.

You would not prompt the user for the paths to the files to delete, you are already using `find` for that:

```
find "$topdir" -type f -empty -delete
```

If you did want a prompt for every file, you would use

```
find "$topdir" -type f -empty -ok rm {} ';'
```

---

Style comments:

- One usually output prompts to the user on standard error:

  ```
  echo "Would you like to delete the files of size zero?: Type yes or no" >&2
  read answer
  ```

  or

  ```
  read -p "Delete files (yes/no): " answer
  ```
- You mix `-size 0` and `-empty` in your two `find` invocations.

Comment: `"${1:-.}"`, with doublequotes, of course?

Comment: @AlexP If you wish. It's not needed in assignments. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694

Comment: thank you! I am still a little lost on the "$topdir" implementation, could you explain a little further?